# Cycles rendering problems

Tags: rendering

I am using trying to use Cycles to render an image on my model, but there are a couple of problems.
There are multiple color issues and, and it doesn't render fully.

[image]
The ground is instead of brown for some reason.

[image]
It doesn't render the entire model.

[image]
This cloud is white for some reason

[image]
The sky and clouds render properly?

[image]
This is the correct render in Eevee.

I am using in Amd video card (5600 Xt) and I used both the Adrenalin and Pro drivers.
If anyone knows the problem, please tell me.
Edit: I found out when I disable light bounces it doesn't display as orange, but the lighting looks terrible. And for some reason the clouds are still completely white. P.S. The lights I have are White.